# create a procedure to create a table in Pl/sql from a select statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a select query

```
select s.site, s.date, s.loaction, s.modified, sysdate p_run_date 
from table s 
where s.site = 123 --p_site
  and s.date >= sysdate -p_date.
```

i want to create a pl/sql procedure to create a table where `p_date` and `p_site` need to be input to the procedure

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do that? We normally do NOT create tables *dynamically* (which is what you'd use in PL/SQL). That procedure would try to create a table with the same name every time you call it (but with different parameters) and **fail** because table with such a name already exists (as it was created the first time you ran the procedure). Therefore, having a one-time procedure is pretty much useless.

If it must be done, oh well ...

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number, par_job in varchar2)
  2  is
  3    l_str varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    l_str := 'create table my_test as ' ||
  6             'select deptno, ename, job, sal ' ||
  7             'from emp ' ||
  8             'where deptno = ' || dbms_assert.enquote_literal(par_deptno) ||
  9             '  and job = '    || dbms_assert.enquote_literal(par_job);
 10    execute immediate l_str;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test(10, 'CLERK');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from my_test;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10 MILLER     CLERK           1300
```

Let's try it again, with different parameters:

```
SQL> exec p_test(20, 'MANAGER');
BEGIN p_test(20, 'MANAGER'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

As I said, it'll fail. What you're trying to do is just wrong. You'd rather create a **view**.